# Долгая запись в бд

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Записываю дынные из файла в postgresql

```
foreach ($ipPool as $ip) {
                $date = new \DateTime($csv[5]);
                 Resource::updateOrCreate([
                    'ip'           => trim($ip),
                ], [
                    'date' => $date
                ]);
            }
```

записей очень много примерно 700 000. Как ускорить загрузку записей в базу?

Comment: добавить составной индекс  `ip`, `date` или `date`, `ip` - смотря что селективнее. думаю, первый вариант

Comment: 700к записей, да по одной - тут практически нет потенции для ускорения. Нужно организовывать пакетную запись, т.е. сразу пачками по дофига записей - и вот уж не знаю, есть ли что подобное в Laravel...

Comment: Вы можете просто использовать Eloquent::insert().

Например:

$data = array(
    array('name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096'),
    array('name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048'),
    //...
);

Coder::insert($data);